# Avoid debug.js file is being download for client

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, knockout.js

I have put below mentioned knockout js reference inside the `_Layout.cshtml` file.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have put `debug.js` file **only for intellisense support** inside the visual studio 2010.

**My Question is :**

How to avoid `debug.js` file is being down loaded for client when I published my application.In other words restrict `debug.js` file only for the development environment(not for the client side download).

**How to do that in ASP.NET ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to have a flag indicating e.g. `DEVELOPMENT_MODE = true;`.  Then wrap the `<script>` declaration with logic that checks that flag, and only includes the script if it's true.

I'm not a `.net` person, but in PHP something like:

```
define('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', true);
...
if(DEVELOPMENT_MODE){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js"></script>';
}
```

Of course, prior to deploying your app you'd set `DEVELOPMENT_MODE` to false (either manually or via Ant, etc).

Cheers